# Using SonarLint with VSCode. How can I change the regex rule S116 for Jave uses?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

I am using Sonarlint with VSCode on a Java project on Windows 10. My project has a variable naming convention such that we use underscores as long as it isn't the first character. These variables are triggering Java Rule S116 "Field names should comply with a naming convention".  The doc on this rule says that the default regex it uses is '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'  It also says:

> Parameters
> *Following parameter values can be set in the
> SonarLint:Rules user settings. In connected mode, server side
> configuration overrides local settings.*
>
> format  Regular expression used to check the field names against.
> (Default value: ^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$)

This strongly implies that the value of the regex can be changed by the user and that it can be done with local configuration. But I can't figure out from this information what exactly do I do to change the value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't a place in the setting GUI for this, but it can be set in the user (not workspace) settings.json file, by adding this entry:

```
"sonarlint.rules": {
  "java:S116": {
      "parameters": {
          "format": "^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"
      }
  }|
}
```

Comment: You may accept the answer to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Do you know where to find the docs for this? How did you find out that this option is called "format"? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/76331073/20031500.

Comment: what if I want to modify only the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

In the settings GUI find the setting for this extension and change it to

```
^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```